# gcc compile error: cast specifies array type

Tags: c, gcc

The following code is perfect valid,

```
int *ia = (int[]){1,3,5,7};
```

but when I compile the next line of code,

```
char *p = (char[]) "abc";
```

gcc says

```
test.c:87: error: cast specifies array type
```

It seems they are casted in the same way. Why did the second one get an err msg?

---

As you guys said, "abc" is a pointer, which cannot be converted to be a pointer. So my another question: why does

```
 char[] s = "abc";
```

is valid. How does the above line of code work when compiling?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is valid because the expression on the right hand side is a C99 *compound literal*, not a cast:

```
int *ia = (int[]){1,3,5,7};    /* Valid */
```

However, this is not valid because it is a *cast-expression*, not a compound literal.  As GCC is telling you, you can't cast to array types:

```
char *p = (char[]) "abc";     /* NOT Valid */
```

You can fix it by making it a proper compound literal - they are denoted by the braces:

```
char *p = (char[]){"abc"};    /* Valid */
```

Comment: This is excellent, because now I can do this: sizeof((char[]){"abcde"})

Comment: @Michael: You could always do `sizeof "abcde"` which is exactly the same - the only differences between the compound literal and the string literal are that the compound literal is modifiable, and that the string literal may share storage with other string literals.

Answer (score 3):

[C11 6.5.2.5p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p3):

> 3. A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name **followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers** is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

**(emphasis mine)**.

I.e., type in parentheses `(char [])`, followed by **brace-enclosed list of initializers**, `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }`.

Since paragraph 6. says that

> 6. All the semantic rules for initializer lists in 6.7.9 also apply to compound literals.

And 6.7.9p14 says

> 14. An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

you can also use `(char []){ "abc" }` to the same effect. Notice that even though `6.7.9p14` allows for an array of `char` be initialized from a string *without* braces, the rules for compound literals deny this, because  `(char []) "abc"` would look like a *cast*.

Answer (score -1):

The first example isn't casting it's array creation.
And there is huge diffrence between char[] and char* : the first one is the array itself and second one is pointer to array. The following should work (not 100% sure):

```
char *p = &((char[]) "abc");
```

Or

```
char *p = &((char[]) "abc")[0];
```