# cast specifies array type error with assaining two dimensional arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I have set a structure type:

```
typedef struct {
    char *snt[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
} sentence;
```

And this line is getting a `cast specifies array type` error:

```
sentence copySentence(sentence *source) {
    sentence nw;
    nw.snt = (char *[])source->snt; //Here is the error
    return nw;
}
```

What is the best fix for this code line and what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc compile error: cast specifies array type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427843/gcc-compile-error-cast-specifies-array-type)

Comment: change `char *sentence[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];` to `char **sentence;` and `malloc` it according to `MAX_LINE_LENGTH`.  Then you'll not need to cast anything.

Comment: Stop writing casts (particulary if you have no idea what you are doing)

Comment: You can write `nw = *source;` instead of that line. Or replace the whole function with `return *source;`  .  This will do a shallow copy.  If you want a 'deep copy' then you need to explain more about how you allocate memory for your sentences.

Comment: `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` is a strange name for the count of how many lines you have.

Answer (score 1):

Both `nw.snt` and `source->snt` are arrays of pointer. To "deep copy" the whole array, you may want to use `memmove(nw.snt, source->snt, MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof (char *));`.

Also, people usually prefer passing a pointer to a struct than pass that struct directly to reduce the cost of argument passing. In this case, you can

```
sentence *copySentence(sentence *source) {
    sentence *nw;
    nw = malloc(sizeof (struct sentence));
    memmove(nw.snt, source->snt, MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof (char *));
    return nw;
}
```

Comment: ...and it will appear a new error asking what is int member... ;)

Comment: I guessed so. BTW you cannot solve OP problem with your solution. It will give you: `error: assignment to expression with array type`

Comment: But then you get error of pointer to local variable, don't you?

Comment: @matyah No, local variables resides on the **stack**, while `malloc()` allocates memory on the **heap** to `nw`.

Comment: @matyah So after `copySentence()` returns, `*nw`, which is on the heap, is not effected.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `snt` as an array of pointers to charactes. You probably mean it t be an array of charactes, or a pointer to an array of characters:

```
char snt[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];    // array of characters to hold your sentence
char *snt;                    // pointer to array of characters
```

When you assign an element to a compatible element, there is no need for a cast and casting is here considered harmful because you prevent the compiler from giving you warnings. Note that you do not *copy* the characters, you only make two structs point to the same sentence.

I leave fixing this to you, as an excercise.